# Adjusting incorrect data of a CSV file data in a Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to read CSV file into a dataframe in Pyspark but I have a CSV file which has mixed data. Part of its data belongs to its adjacent column. Is there any way to modify the dataframe in python to get the output dataframe as expected.

Sample CSV

```
ID   , Name  
'1'  , 'Alice'
'2B' , 'ob'
'3Ri' , 'chard'
```

Expected Output

```
ID, Name  
1, 'Alice'
2, 'Bob'
3, 'Richard'
```

Comment: Where does the data come from? There is no way of fixing it at the source? _Is there any way to modify the dataframe in python to get the output dataframe as expected._ That depends entirely on the format. Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Its one of the parts of the coding exercise. Our task is to clean the data and apply some transformations and actions on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by making use of `regexp_extract` from `pyspark.sql.functions`.

My approach would be something like this:

```py
#read with a different separator so df generated with a single column
df = spark.read.csv('filename',header=True,sep='|')

#renamed the column name with irr (to make it easy to call)
newcolnames=['irr']
for c,n in zip(df.columns,newcolnames):
    df=df.withColumnRenamed(c,n)

df.withColumn('ID',regexp_extract(df['irr'],r'(\d+)',1))
  .withColumn('Name',regexp_extract(df['irr'],'your_regex_pattern',0))
  .drop(df['irr']).show()
```

Comment: This really gave me a kisk-start. I have added `'[a-zA-Z\s,]+'`  as my regex pattern. Since the data got extra comma's, I used  `dff.withColumn('Name', regexp_replace('Name', ',', ''))`  to remove them. Thanks mate.

Comment: Glad it helped.